# Controlling the actions with org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I have a python code in "/abc/hello" with `-rwxr-xr-x` and I have a [[/abc/hello]], I click the link to run hello code. Can I change the action so that I can edit (open an editor) `abc/hello` file?

I tried this

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
 '(
    ("edit" . "mate %s")))
```

with `[[edit:/abc/hello]]`, but it  doesn't work.

I also tried `file:/abc/hello`, but it doesn't work neither.

### SOLVED

```
("mate" . "shell:/usr/local/bin/mate %s")
```

And to turn confirmation off

```
(setq org-confirm-shell-link-function nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Leo Alekseyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133234/leo-alekseyev) gave me an answer to this quetion at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046268/how-can-i-use-specific-protocol-in-my-case-txmt-with-org-mode/5046537#5046537).

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct, so it will not show on "unanswered" list.