# How can I use specific protocol (in my case : txmt) with Org mode?

Tags: emacs, textmate, org-mode

I have TextMate running on Mac, and it has [txmt](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html) protocol, that I can use as on web browser such as `txmt://open/?url=file:///Users/smcho/smcho/bin/rst2html`. I can use TextMate for editing rst2html.

However, when I tried to use this protocol with Org-mode as `[txmt://open/?url=file:///Users/smcho/smcho/bin/rst2html]`, instead of opening TextMate, the rst2html binary is running.

I tried

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
 '(
   ("edit" . "txmt://open/?url=file://%s")
))
```

to use `[edit:/Users/smcho/smcho/bin/rst2html]`, but I get the same result.

How can I use specific protocol (in my case : txmt) with Org mode?

### ADDED

It's not using protocol, but one can run open and edit some file with this command.

```
("edit" . "shell:/usr/local/bin/mate %s")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe org-mode can only handle links specified on [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links) (and maybe a few other link types, e.g. links to git repos, courtesy of contrib packages).  I'm not a TextMate/Apple user, but it seems to me that txmt:// protocol in the question is just a handler TextMate sets up for the installed browsers; you can't expect this to work with org.

The real question is -- can you set up a link so that a particular file is opened in TextMate.  The most straightforward way is to issue a shell command that will open the file in TextMate.  Using org-link-abbrev-alist, you could do something like `("edit" . "shell:/path/to/textmate_binary %s &")`.  You'll also want to use `(setq org-confirm-shell-link-function nil)` to suppress the confirmation prompt.

In general, it is always possible to create custom link types as described [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html); this involves writing the handler function in elisp.  In this case, this would be a call to start TextMate using e.g. `start-process`.  This would be a cleaner solution, but probably not worth the extra effort.  In customizing org link handlers, it is usually sufficient to set up shortcuts via `org-link-abbrev-alist`, or set up handlers based on extension via `org-file-apps`.

Comment: The org-mode runs the command if it's executable file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044474/controlling-the-actions-with-org-mode), my other approach is to run elisp code in org-mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043895/how-to-call-elisp-function-within-org-mode), but I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: @proseek: aha, here's what works (my example is with gedit, since I'm not on a mac) `(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
 '(("gedit" . "shell:/usr/bin/gedit %s")))`.  It'll ask you for a confirmation; you might be able to toggle those confirmations off.

Comment: It works fine, thanks. BTW, do you know how to turn the confirmation off?

Comment: @proseek: (setq org-confirm-shell-link-function nil) (edited answer to include this)

Comment: Thanks, Leo. You actually answered my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044474/controlling-the-actions-with-org-mode

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I recently had a similar issue with links to Papers.app on my Mac (http://www.mekentosj.com).  Papers provides a link protocol ("papers2:")for referring to documents in its Library, for example: "papers2://publication/uuid/4319127A-3FD5-4DB9-A3F8-1881AC937B74"

I wanted to be able to store these links in my org-mode document and have org open Papers.app when this link is visited. (\C-c\C-o)

On the Mac, you can specify links like this as the argument to the "open" shell command, and the appropriate application handles them.

The code below configures org-mode to send any link that looks like it has a protocol to "open" via the shell.  The documentation for `org-open-link-functions` indicates that this hook is called after known external links are handled, but before textual searches begin.

**This configuration should work for the original TextMate question with no modification.**

```
(defun org-pass-link-to-system (link)
  (if (string-match "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:" link)
    (shell-command (concat "open " link))
    nil)
  )

(add-hook 'org-open-link-functions 'org-pass-link-to-system)
```